# JavaScript event handler arguments

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var ans_el = document.createElement( 'input' );
ans_el.setAttribute( 'id', unique_int_value );
ans_el.setAttribute( 'type', 'radio' );
ans_el.setAttribute( 'name', 'group' );
ans_el.setAttribute( 'value', 'myValue' );
ans_el.onclick = myFunction( this.id, this.value ); 

// Add ans_el to DOM.

function myFunction( index, value ) { // do something }
```

This, of course, does not work as expected.  At least not in Firefox 3.6.  What happens is the `onclick` event is fired when the element is created and the arguments passed to `myFunction` are null. After the element is added to the DOM, the `onclick` event does not fire when the radio button is select.

I'd be grateful if anyone has some insight into what's happening here, and/or how dynamically adding event handlers can be accomplished.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to give a reference to a function for onclick; you are currently executing the function and assigning that result to the onclick handler. This is closer to what you want:

```
ans_el.onclick = function(e) {
   myFunction(ans_el.id, ans_el.value);
};
```

UPDATED: Decided to use event.target for a clearer example since Andir brought it up.

```
ans_el.onclick = function(e) {
   myFunction(e.target.id, e.target.value);
};
```

Comment: you can also get the id/value from the e.target object.  (e.target.id ...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I did something similar that seems to work:

ans_el.setAttribute( 'onclick', 'myFunc( this.id, this.value )' );

I've only tested this in FF, I'm sure Internet Explorer will require prodigious hoop-jumping to accomplish the same.  I'm very tempted to tell my users that I.E. will not be supported.

Comment: That will work, but using strings of js code to be eval()ed like that is generally frowned upon. It is usually slow, buggy, and presents a number of security problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil/198031#198031